# In Shiny/R how to synchronize two sets of tab panels?

Tags: r, shiny

I need to click on the tabpanel label "Panel 2" and on the right the plot on "Panel Right Chart 2" will shows up (The chart with green line).

Bellow is my code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  column(
    width = 6,
    
    tabsetPanel(
      
      tabPanel(
        strong("Panel 1")
      ),
      
      tabPanel(
        strong("Panel 2")
      ),
      
      tabPanel(
        strong("Panel 3")
      ))),
  
  column(
    width = 6,
    
    tabsetPanel(
      
      tabPanel(
        strong("Panel Right Chart 1"),
        plotOutput("chart1")
      ),
      
      tabPanel(
        strong("Panel Right Chart 2"),
        plotOutput("chart2")
      ),
      
      tabPanel(
        strong("Panel Right Chart 3"),
        plotOutput("chart3")
      )))
  
  
    
    

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$chart1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars,aes(cyl,mpg)) + geom_line(color = 'red')
  })
  
  output$chart2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars,aes(cyl,mpg)) + geom_line(color = 'green')
  })
  
  output$chart3 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars,aes(cyl,mpg)) + geom_line(color = 'blue')
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You are trying to synchronize two different sets of `tabPanel`s? Otherwise could you just put the graphs on respective panel?

Comment: @DanAdams  exactly! I want to synchronize them. I will edit the question.

Comment: This doesn't directly solve your issue, but the example [here](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#dynamic-visibility) from Mastering Shiny seems like it might help get you close.

Comment: @DanAdams I think the answer is on updatetabsetPanel(). I will study it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DanAdams pointed you to, and you responded with Laura, `updateTabsetPanel` is key. When I've done this in the past, I would use `observeEvent`, whenever a tab on the first set of tabs is chosen, then it updates the second set of tabs with the corresponding choice. Here's it is with your code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  column(
    width = 6,
    
    tabsetPanel(id = "FirstTabs",
      
      tabPanel(value = 1,
        strong("Panel 1")
      ),
      
      tabPanel(value = 2,
        strong("Panel 2")
      ),
      
      tabPanel(value = 3,
        strong("Panel 3")
      ))),
  
  column(
    width = 6,
    
    tabsetPanel(id = "SecondTabs",
      
      tabPanel(value = "1",
        strong("Panel Right Chart 1"),
        plotOutput("chart1")
      ),
      
      tabPanel(value = "2",
        strong("Panel Right Chart 2"),
        plotOutput("chart2")
      ),
      
      tabPanel(value = "3",
        strong("Panel Right Chart 3"),
        plotOutput("chart3")
      )))
  
  
  
  
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$chart1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars,aes(cyl,mpg)) + geom_line(color = 'red')
  })
  
  output$chart2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars,aes(cyl,mpg)) + geom_line(color = 'green')
  })
  
  output$chart3 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars,aes(cyl,mpg)) + geom_line(color = 'blue')
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$FirstTabs, {
    if(input$FirstTabs == "1") {
      updateTabsetPanel(session, "SecondTabs",
                        selected = "1")
      
    }
    if(input$FirstTabs == "2") {
      updateTabsetPanel(session, "SecondTabs",
                        selected = "2")
      
    }
    if(input$FirstTabs == "3") {
      updateTabsetPanel(session, "SecondTabs",
                        selected = "3")
      
    }

  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This looks nice! Any way to avoid repeating the `if` statement in `observeEvent`, if you had 50 tabs for example? Maybe directly set `selected == input$FirstTabs`?

Comment: Figured it out... see answer below.

Answer (score 2):

A small tweak on the answer from Silentdveildoll - I just modified the `observeEvent` call so that the logic to update the panel doesn't have any `if` statements and simply updates to whatever is selected in `input$FirstTabs`. This simplifies the code and will scale much better if there are more than just a few tabs.

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  column(
    width = 6,
    
    tabsetPanel(id = "FirstTabs",
                
                tabPanel(value = 1,
                         strong("Panel 1")
                ),
                
                tabPanel(value = 2,
                         strong("Panel 2")
                ),
                
                tabPanel(value = 3,
                         strong("Panel 3")
                ))),
  
  column(
    width = 6,
    tabsetPanel(id = "SecondTabs",
                
                tabPanel(value = "1",
                         strong("Panel Right Chart 1"),
                         plotOutput("chart1")
                ),
                
                tabPanel(value = "2",
                         strong("Panel Right Chart 2"),
                         plotOutput("chart2")
                ),
                
                tabPanel(value = "3",
                         strong("Panel Right Chart 3"),
                         plotOutput("chart3")
                ))) 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$chart1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars,aes(cyl,mpg)) + geom_line(color = 'red')
  })
  
  output$chart2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars,aes(cyl,mpg)) + geom_line(color = 'green')
  })
  
  output$chart3 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars,aes(cyl,mpg)) + geom_line(color = 'blue')
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$FirstTabs, {
      updateTabsetPanel(session, "SecondTabs",
                        selected = input$FirstTabs)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Ooh that's better, nice!